# Trouble with my angular project and my Apache Server

Tags: angular, apache, production

---

Look, i recently finished my project and went happy to send it to my Apache server.

My Apache server has the standard folder structure **www** as the source and inside of it you put you files.

I ran the command in my project: `ng build --prod`, and gave me the following files:
[my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFH6H.png)

So i copied the content of the dist file and paste it in the path: `./www/test/FitProject` in my Apache folder and ran my server.
But the console hitted me with an error saying:

1. localhost:8080/Polyfills.js  error 404, this file wasn't found
2. localhost:8080/Runtime.js  error 404, this file wasn't found
3. localhost:8080/styles.css  error 404, this file wasn't found

So i tought, maybe it is searching for these files in the source folder(www) so i copied these files and paste it in the www folder and work out just fine.

> So what can i do to stop this error and tells to the angular project to look for these files inside it's own folder, not in www ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a option `--base-href` when build a project.

```
ng build --prod --base-href /test/FitProject/
```